# How can I implement a search service which uses proximity to a location as a ranking parameter

Tags: algorithm, search, geolocation, data-modeling, data-mining

I have a data set over which I need to implement a location based search service. I will filter the data initially based on keyword arguments and then I need to sort them based on proximity to the user's location. How do I go about implementing this, some pointers on the kind of algorithms/approaches to use, or tips on modeling the data will be really helpful.

Comment: Well to sort them based on proximity you do a sort... which sorts by proximity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a database with geo support like [postgis](http://postgis.refractions.net/):

```
SELECT * FROM points ORDER BY distance(point1, point2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach -
you can think of Apache Solr (open source search engine) @ http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
It will help you to search across keywords and provides geo spatial capabilities.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

Caution - may be an overhead or completely out of context as well, suggested just as an option. As am not sure for the quatity of data, format of the data, what search capabilties you need.

Answer (score 0):

When I add a listing to my DB, I run the address/postcode though a geocoding service such as Google or Yahoo. I then store these lat/lng values with the listing. When the user searches I take their location and again run this through a geocode, and then I can sort by proximity.

Similar to something like this:

http://maurus.net/resources/distance-queries/

Answer (score -1):

Here's an idea where you build it without using API from other services.
I assume you want to show all the data to the client. If not you could query your DB with min max lat,lon values to restrict the area.

Let's imagine the client wants to see closest restaurants from coordinate x,y
From clientside you send webservice query showdata(lat,lon,type)

At serverside: First you query your DB, select where type == restaurant. This give you a list of restaurants with lat,lon coordinates. You iterate the list and calculate the distance from the clients lat,lon values and insert the result in the items list.

```
class Item 
{
  Distance
  Name
  Lat
  Lon
}    
List<Item> items
```

As the last step you sort your items list by Distance value and return the result to your client.